# How do I run Apache & IIS 7 on the same IP address (different ports)?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, port

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine which is running Apache at the moment for a public facing PHP site (port 80). IIS is stopped.

I now need to start running IIS on the same IP address as Apache, but I can happily use another port as it's internal only e.g. 8080. We have no other IP addresses available.

I presume it can be done, but I'm new to Apache and need to ensure that I don't break the current PHP site when starting IIS. I understand that IIS tends to hog all ports on an IP by default? Or has that changed since IIS 6?

What configuration steps do I need to take to achieve this?

Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for IIS7 involves:

> Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0:
>
> ```
> 1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
> 2. Select the Web site that you wish to configure.
> 3. In the Action pane, click Bindings.
> 4. Click Add to add a new site binding, or click Edit to change an existing binding.
> 5. Click OK to apply the changes.
> ```

From [How to change the TCP port for IIS Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605)

Comment: Thanks, didn't think just doing that would work... Glad it was simple.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this for Apache: [Binding to Addresses and Ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/bind.html)

The short version modify the `listen` line:

> Listen `<ipaddress>:<port>`

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Things have moved on a bit since 2010 and these days we really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.